# .NET MAUI GestureRecognizer Tapped vs Command

Tags: c#, .net, command, code-behind, .net-maui

Lets say I have a ListView whose DataTemplate is a Grid. On the Grid I have a GestureRecognizer

```
<Grid.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" Command="{Binding CmdTapped, Source={x:Reference root}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
</Grid.GestureRecognizers>
```

Notice that I have a code-behind handler and a view model command tied to the recognizer.

The code-behind simply invokes a haptic

```
private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HapticFeedback.Default.Perform(HapticFeedbackType.Click);
}
```

The command simply sleeps for 5 seconds

```
private void RowSelected()
{
   Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

When I run this on my iPhone and touch the grid, I see the code-behind get called right away but the vibration only happens after the viewmodel's 5 second wait.

I put this contrived example together because nothing I try affects the grid in the row of a ListView (or even a BindableTemplate) - color change, text change, haptic feedback - until after the viewmodel is done, which in my case is a PushAsync so the affect of the changes become moot when the new page appears.

Nothing changes if I remove the code-behind and put the haptic in the viewmodel just prior to the sleep. The haptic only vibrates when the command's handler exits. This is not useful if the command has some work to do and all you wanted to do is let the user know that work has begun.

Comment: Why do you have 2 seperate events for the same thing?

Comment: I only want the command. I created the code behind because I wanted to try it. In any case, it doesn't matter, as i stated. The haptic doesn't vibrate until the command handler exits.

Comment: That's probably because Command is invoked before the Tapped event and since you are calling Thread sleep it holds the thread..

Comment: The Tapped event runs and finishes (from what i can tell in the debugger) during the sleep. But as I said, even if I delete the Tapped, and put the haptic as the first line in the command, the vibration doesn't happen until after the command exits.

Comment: Why are you using `Thread.Sleep`... Why not use Task delay. You might wanna read what Thread.Sleep does and then you will know what is happening to you is not an issue... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=net-6.0, You can probably also use Thread.Suspend

Comment: Well Nvm Thread Suspend is deprecated https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.suspend?view=net-6.0

Comment: You can try to call your tactile incident asynchronously.

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT HapticFeedback doesn't have an Async method. I tried awaiting on Task.Run(() => HapticFeedback.Perform()) in the code-behind handler but iOS throws UIKitThreadAccessException "UIKit method can only be invoked from UI thread.

Comment: IVibration lets you start and stop the vibrate functionality for a desired amount of time. You can try adding click vibration manually.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device/vibrate?Tabs=android